# Is it possible to perform more validation after validationSchema, Yup, is passed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

Currently, I am doing some validation such as min length, max length, required and so on using Yup in combination. I wonder if i could perform some more validation which need request and response from server side after Yup validation is passed?

For example, i need a valid phone number format to be input first and after validate is passed, then I want to request to my backend to check if this phone number is existed. In case if it is already existed, then just set errors.phone: "Phone number is already registered." and show it inside ui using `{touched.phone && errors.phone && <p>{errors.phone}</p>}`. Please help shine me some light. I could not find any solutions for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.test`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestname-string-message-string--function-test-function-schema)

As you can see in the docs example

```
let asyncJimmySchema = string().test(
  'is-jimmy',
  '${path} is not Jimmy',
  async (value) => (await fetch('/is-jimmy/' + value)).responseText === 'true',
});
```

The third paramether can be an async function and there you will make a call to your backend.

## Edit:

If you want to validate only `onBlur` you can change Formik Prop [`validateOnBlur`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#validateonblur-boolean) and [`validateOnChange`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#validateonchange-boolean).
The default value of both are `true` but if you set `validateOnChange` to false, it will only run validations `onBlur`. Notice that this will happen to **all fields**.

If you only that to happen only to one field, you will need to use field's [`validate`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field#validate) prop and pass a function that receives the `touched` of the field to check it before calling the async function.

Comment: i want to check if phone number is existed or not yet after onBlur, how can i do that?

Comment: `{touched.phone && errors.phone && <p>{errors.phone}</p>}` this will show the error onBlur and when it doesn't match. Is this not working? Please provide more information about your code if this isn't working

Comment: i will feedback in the next few days after back to work. Thanks anyway, @Vencovsky

Comment: Hi @Vencovsky, I manage to make it works now but it does call backend single word i type and as well as onblur. But can I check only after onblur instead of both because it is too slow as it always request backend?

Comment: @Vencovsky this edit looks good but i feel so frustrated using with formik now. I use to tried to add onBlurHandler method by myself to only one Formik Field and then field always call that method everytime they got blur.

Comment: @jujuzi sorry but that's how you can do it using formik  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`string.test()`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestname-string-message-string--function-test-function-schema):

```
phone: Yup.string()
        .matches(/phone-number-regex/, 'Invalide phone number')
        .test(
          'phone',
          'Phone number is already registered',
           async (value) => (await fetch(`/validate-phone/${value}`)).responseText === 'true',
        ),
...
```

**Demo**: https://runkit.com/fraction01/yup-async-test

Comment: i want to check if phone number is existed or not yet after onBlur, how can i do that?